# Command prompt closes without taking input

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, cmd, argv

Why am I not being able to enter anything? The program on running doesn't wait for my input and the cmd prints `Enter a Filename` and closes. I am executing it on Visual Studio 2008.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        if(argc<2)
            printf("\nEnter a filename");
        else
        { 
            //code
        }
        getch();
        return 0;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `The program '[3192] bst.exe: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`  You somehow are not actually programming in C++.  Use the proper project template to get your project started.  Use Win32 + Win32 Console Application.

Comment: @Hans Passant - `getch()` should still work in C++/CLI... It doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing something is in the buffer. Try seeing what it is?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc<2)
        printf("\nEnter a filename");
    else
    { 
        //code
    }

    while (true)
    {
        int c;
        c = getch();
        printf( ": %d\n", c );
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

After your response it appears there is the letter b in your input stream when your program is called. Not sure how to explain that. Are you trying to get a whole string and not just a character?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char string [256];
    if(argc<2)
    {
        printf("Enter a filename:");
        gets (string);
    }
    else
    { 
        //assign string to argv[1]
    }


   printf ("Your filename is: %s\n",string);
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You can send data to stdin when you run a program in the debugger (something like `< file` in Debugging/Command Line Arguments). Maybe that is the data you see?

Answer (score 0):

You should usually end, not start, the outputted string with newline (because on `stdout` a newline may flush buffers). Or you should call `fflush(stdout);` before your call to `getch()`. So try with `printf("Enter a filename:\n");`

Comment: tried both, after printing `Enter a filename` as I press a key to input it closes. On output window it shows `The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x428) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xb70) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[3192] bst.exe: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[3192] bst.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
`

Comment: Probably a matter of configuring your compiler. I cannot help, I never used Windows! Did you consider using Linux?

Comment: Then read the documentation of your compiler, and find out how to compile such a simple program. I've heard that on Windows graphical programs (which are the default) are compiled differently than console programs (which are rare).

Comment: `getch()` is from `stdin` not `stdout`. Do not understand your reasoning here.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your program without debugging (`Ctrl+F5` in Visual Studio).  This will keep the cmd window open after the program has finished.

(edit)Perhaps you want to do something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        string filename;
        if(argc<2)
        {
            printf("\nEnter a filename");
            cin >> filename;
        }
        else
        { 
            //code
        }
        // getch(); // Use Ctrl+F5 instead
        return 0;
    }
```

`getch()` only gets 1 char from input stream.

Comment: Did that.. After printing `Enter a filename` as I entered the first character, it said `Press any key to continue...` and as I pressed it got closed.